# Draw variable number of rectangles within WPF Grid cells?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF Grid which is 3 columns wide and 8 rows:

```
<Window x:Class="Container.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1000">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I am using this to draw something like this:
[image]

Every cell in the first and third columns may have a different number of rectangles. Also, the width of each rectangle may be different and change at run-time. The width will be proportionate to a number (known at run-time and continually-changing).

What is the best way to draw these rectangles?

Comment: I suspect you may need to take a step back and describe in more detail exactly what it is you're trying to achieve, there's probably a better solution than `Grid`.

Comment: @MarkFeldman see image I have added to the question

Comment: You're in luck...apart from being a day-trader in a previous life I also spent two years writing web, desktop and mobile trading software for the biggest financial trading company in my country. So yeah, this makes perfect sense! :) One quick question first, are you open to doing things the "proper" way i.e. with a view model and data-binding? Or would you prefer at this stage to do everything in code-behind?

Comment: @MarkFeldman ah nice, you know exactly where I'm going with this then! C# isn't my primary language but yes I would like to keep it clean and separate concerns. Eventually I would like to add the ability to enter a timestamp and begin the book from that point (replaying, effectively). At the moment I have just hacked together the above XAML, but the orders will (obviously) need to be added programatically. I'm going to look across all visible orders for the largest order quantity and then size all orders in proportion to that largest qty.

Comment: Ok, lemme come back to you with an answer in a bit. This is very easy to do, but if WPF isn't your strong point then I'll need to do a little explaining.

Comment: This should be pretty easy using MVVM.  If set up properly, just changing adding and removing some order records should automatically propagate out to the UI without you really having to deal with any special events.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Much (much) appreciated!

Comment: @MarkFeldman There's one bit I forgot to mention: I'm going to keep the number of rows constant, let's say 30 rows. As the best bid/ask increases (or decreases), I'll wait until it's say 4 or 5 rows from the top (or bottom) and then I will redraw the orderbook, with the current best bid/ask now being the middle row.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I've come up with after about an hour of fiddling ([GitHub Repo](https://github.com/BradleyUffner/BuySellOrders)):
[image]

I'm using the MVVM pattern to make the UI as easy as possible.  Right now, it just populates with some random data.

The XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="BuySellOrders.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BuySellOrders"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="15">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Prices}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PriceEntryVm}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Padding="5"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                            <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Right" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BuyOrders}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OrderVm}">
                                        <Border
                                            Width="{Binding Path=Qty}"
                                            Margin="5"
                                            Background="red"
                                            BorderBrush="Black"
                                            BorderThickness="1" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Border>
                        <Border
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="8"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{Binding Path=Price}" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Padding="5"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SellOrders}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OrderVm}">
                                        <Border
                                            Width="{Binding Path=Qty}"
                                            Margin="5"
                                            Background="red"
                                            BorderBrush="Black"
                                            BorderThickness="1" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The view models:

```
class MainWindowVm : ViewModel
{
    public MainWindowVm()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();

        Prices = new ObservableCollection<PriceEntryVm>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            var entry = new PriceEntryVm();
            Prices.Add(entry);
            entry.BuyOrders.CollectionChanged += OnOrderChanged;
            entry.SellOrders.CollectionChanged += OnOrderChanged;

            entry.Price = (decimal)110.91 + (decimal)i / 100;

            var numBuy = rnd.Next(5);
            for (int orderIndex = 0; orderIndex < numBuy; orderIndex++)
            {
                var order = new OrderVm();
                order.Qty = rnd.Next(70) + 5;
                entry.BuyOrders.Add(order);
            }

            var numSell = rnd.Next(5);
            for (int orderIOndex = 0; orderIOndex < numSell; orderIOndex++)
            {
                var order = new OrderVm();
                order.Qty = rnd.Next(70) + 5;
                entry.SellOrders.Add(order);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnOrderChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                var order = item as OrderVm;
                if (order.Qty > LargestOrder)
                {
                    LargestOrder = order.Qty;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int _largestOrder;
    public int LargestOrder
    {
        get { return _largestOrder; }
        private set { SetValue(ref _largestOrder, value); }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<PriceEntryVm> Prices { get; }
}

public class PriceEntryVm: ViewModel
{
    public PriceEntryVm()
    {
        BuyOrders = new OrderList(this);
        SellOrders = new OrderList(this);
    }

    private Decimal _price;
    public Decimal Price
    {
        get {return _price;}
        set {SetValue(ref _price, value);}
    }

    public OrderList BuyOrders { get; }
    public OrderList SellOrders { get; }
}

public class OrderList : ObservableCollection<OrderVm>
{
    public OrderList(PriceEntryVm priceEntry)
    {
        PriceEntry = priceEntry;
    }

    public PriceEntryVm PriceEntry { get; }

}

public class OrderVm : ViewModel
{
    private int _qty;
    public int Qty
    {
        get { return _qty; }
        set { SetValue(ref _qty, value); }
    }

}
```

I had to make some assumptions about the naming of things, but hopefully you should get the basic idea of what's going on.

It's structured as a list of `PriceEntry`, each of which contains a `Price`, and a `BuyOrders` and `SellOrders` properties.

`BuyOrders` and `SellOrders` are just lists of orders that have a `Quantity` property.

The XAML binds the list of price entries to a template that contains a 3 column grid.  The first and 3rd columns of that grid bound to another set of item controls for each list of orders.  The template for each order is just a border with a `Width` bound to the `Quantity` of the order.

All the binds means that just updating a property, or adding an order to either the buy or sell list of a price entry will automatically propagate to the UI. Adding or removing a `PriceEntry` will also automatically adjust the UI.

I haven't implemented your automatic scaling yet, but the basic idea would be to use a `ValueConverter` on the `Quantity` binding, to make it automatically adjust to the largest order.

As an extra note, it uses [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgentOctal.WpfLib) to provide some of the MVVM boiler-plate code, but you should be able to use anything you want, as long as it gives you `INotifyPropertyChanged` support.

---

Here is a bonus screen capture showing the dynamic nature of MVVM updating the UI based on a timer.

[image]

This only needed a few lines of code to randomly pick a row, then randomly pick an order on the row, then add or subtract a small random amount from the quantity.

```
_updateTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
_updateTimer.Tick += OnUpdate;
_updateTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01);
_updateTimer.Start();

private void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var entryIndex = _rnd.Next(Prices.Count);
    var entry = Prices[entryIndex];

    OrderList list;
    list = _rnd.Next(2) == 1 ?
               entry.BuyOrders :
               entry.SellOrders;

    if (list.Any())
    {
        var order = list[_rnd.Next(list.Count)];
        order.Qty += _rnd.Next(0, 8) - 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bradley, many thanks for this. How do I access class ViewModel? Do I need to import the class from somewhere? A .net library? Where should I place the code for MainWindowVm? Does it matter where in the project? These C# projects (particularly with the GUI code) are very new to me.

Comment: `ViewModel` comes from the Nuget package I mentioned at the bottom of the answer.  Just install the package and you should be good to go!  It just gives some shortcuts for `INotifyPropertyChanged` support, which is what lets changes to properties automatically update the UI.  You can use any package you want, like MVVMLight, or event implement it manually if you want.

Comment: I've added a link to a GitHub repo containing the source code to the top of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Right then, here goes....

This is exactly the kind of thing you want to use data-binding for. You can try and do things manually if you like, but your code will quickly become very messy if you do. WPF lets you do things the old-school way (i.e. similar to WinForms et al) but that was really to facilitate porting of legacy code. I won't go into too much detail about MVVM (plenty of info on the net about it), but you can get started by using NuGet to add MVVMLightLibs or some other MVVM framework to your project and then you assign your main window a view model by doing something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

So now it's time for the view model itself, which is a model of the data structures that you want your view to display:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<PriceLevel> PriceLevels { get; } = new ObservableCollection<PriceLevel>
    {
        new PriceLevel(110.98, new int[]{ }, new int[]{ }),
        new PriceLevel(110.97, new int[]{ }, new int[]{ }),
        new PriceLevel(110.96, new int[]{ }, new int[]{ }),
        new PriceLevel(110.95, new int[]{ }, new int[]{ 5 }),
        new PriceLevel(110.94, new int[]{ }, new int[]{ 3, 8 }),
        new PriceLevel(110.93, new int[]{ 8, 3, 5, }, new int[]{ }),
        new PriceLevel(110.92, new int[]{ 3 }, new int[]{ }),
        new PriceLevel(110.91, new int[]{ }, new int[]{ }),
    };
}

public class PriceLevel
{
    public double Price { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<int> BuyOrders { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<int> SellOrders { get; }

    public PriceLevel(double price, IEnumerable<int> buyOrders, IEnumerable<int> sellOrders)
    {
        this.Price = price;
        this.BuyOrders = new ObservableCollection<int>(buyOrders);
        this.SellOrders = new ObservableCollection<int>(sellOrders);
    }
}
```

If you don't already know, `ObservableCollection` is very similar to list but it propegrates change notification, so when you make your view display the data in it your GUI will update automatically whenever the list changes. This `MainViewModel` class contains an `ObservableCollection` of type `PriceLevel`, and each `PriceLevel` contains the price and the lists of buy and sell orders. This means you'll be able to add and remove price points, and also add and remove the orders in the price points, and your front-end will reflect those changes.

So on to the front end itself:

```xml
<Window.Resources>

    <!-- Style to display order list as horizontal list of red rectangles -->
    <Style x:Key="OrderListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
        <!-- Set ItemsPanel to a horizontal StackPanel -->
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <!-- Display each item in the order list as a red rectangle and scale x by 8*size -->
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5" >
                        <Rectangle Width="{Binding}" Height="20" Fill="Red">
                            <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="8" ScaleY="1" />
                            </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Style to make Price cells vertically aligned -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- This style centers the column's header text -->
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<!-- This datagrid displays the main list of PriceLevels -->
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PriceLevels}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" RowHeight="30">
    
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <!-- The buy orders column -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Buy orders" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BuyOrders}" Style="{StaticResource OrderListStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!-- The price column -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Price}" />

        <!-- The sell orders column -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sell Orders" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SellOrders}" Style="{StaticResource OrderListStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Looks a bit full-on, but if you break it down into sections it's actually pretty straightforward. The main different between this and what you've been trying to do is that I'm using a `DataGrid`. This is basically a `Grid` control that's had extra functionality added to make it respond dynamically to data that it's been bound to. It also has a lot of extra stuff we dont' need (editing, column resize/reordering etc) so I've turned all that off. The `DataGrid` binds to `PriceLevels` in the view model, so it will display a vertical list showing each one. I've then explicitly declared the 3 columns you're after. The middle one is easy, it's just text, so `DataGridTextColumn` will, do the job. The other two are horizontal arrays of rectangles, so I've used `DataGridTemplateColumn` which allows me to customize exactly how they look. This customization is mostly done in the `OrderListStyle` at the very top of the XAML which sets `ItemsPanel` to a horizontal `StackPanel` and sets `ItemTemplate` to a rectangle. There's also a bit of XAML in there to scale the rectangle by a constant, according to the value of the integer it's displaying in the order list.

Here's the result:

[image]

I know the XAML might seem a little full-on, but keep in mind this is now fully data-bound to that view model and it will automatically update in response to changes. This little bit of extra work at the start results in MUCH cleaner update code which is also easier to test and debug.

Hope this is what you're after, if you have any questions let me know and we can take it into chat.

UPDATE: If you want to see the dynamic update in action then add this to your main view model's constructor, it just adds and removes orders randomly:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        var row = this.PriceLevels[rng.Next(this.PriceLevels.Count())]; // get random row
        switch (rng.Next(4))
        {
            case 0: row.BuyOrders.Add(1 + rng.Next(5)); break;
            case 1: row.SellOrders.Add(1 + rng.Next(5)); break;
            case 2: if (row.BuyOrders.Count() > 0) row.BuyOrders.RemoveAt(rng.Next(row.BuyOrders.Count())); break;
            case 3: if (row.SellOrders.Count() > 0) row.SellOrders.RemoveAt(rng.Next(row.SellOrders.Count())); break;
        }
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Mark, amazing stuff. Just got a question as I'm not sure if you saw this comment of mine: "I'm going to keep the number of rows constant, let's say 30 rows. As the best bid/ask increases (or decreases), I'll wait until it's say 4 or 5 rows from the top (or bottom) and then I will redraw the orderbook, with the current best bid/ask now being the middle row.". Does your answer allow this re-basing of the best bid/ask to the middle row?

Comment: The fact that he uses an `ObservableCollection` means that adding or removing rows will automatically update the UI.  Once the collection gets enough items in it, just clear the list, and repopulate it with refreshed data.  Both of our answers use the same basic concept, and you should be able to get something really nice between us.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. In that case just make the `Price` field in the `PriceLevel` class a string and for each empty row create one with that value set to the empty string and now items in the list. If you do this you might want to rename it PriceLevelViewModel instead, which is what it's supposed to be really i.e. a model of what you're seeing in the view.

Comment: @BradleyUffner thanks for that. I haven't ignored your answer, just quickly trying this before I go to sleep. I may not reply for a good few hours until tomorrow night.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Apologies if this is a daft question (I haven't done C# for years) but 1) Do I need to import something to access ViewModelBase? 2) Where would you place the code for MainViewModel? I assume a separate file. Does it have to be in a particular folder within the solution?

Comment: @user997112 Not a problem, don't worry about it!  It's been a while since I got to do anything in WPF, and your question caught my eye, and gave me a good excuse to play a little bit.  I'm still trying to puzzle out *exactly* how I want to get the dynamic scaling to work. That will be the really interesting part for me.

Comment: ViewModelBase is the base class that the MVVMLightLibs library uses. Probably a bit confusing, it's not actually needed in this particular case. If you start using data-binding to any serious degree though you will need it almost immediately. It handles property change notification for things like properties etc (my exact example doesn't need it because I'm only updating lists and ObserveableCollection does it for those). MainViewModel doesn't need to be in any particular folder, some people put vms in the same folder as views and others lump all vms together.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Ah so MVVMLightLibs is a separate library, from the normal .net installation, which I will need to install? Is it just a msi that I run? Don't need to configure anything else?

Comment: It's a freely available Nuget package from here  https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight

Comment: @BradleyUffner Okay, managed to get it with using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

Comment: Is there a compile error on this line (or is my .net too old?) public ObservableCollection<PriceLevel> PriceLevels { get; } = new ObservableCollection<PriceLevel> I get "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PriceLevels' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=65613256)'. BindingExpression:Path=PriceLevels; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=65613256); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')"

Comment: I also had to add "set" alongside "get" within PriceLevel class because of the constructor initialisation: this.Price = price;
        this.BuyOrders = new ObservableCollection<int>(buyOrders);
        this.SellOrders = new ObservableCollection<int>(sellOrders);